# How to create a Vector of Vectors of Objects of a Class

Tags: c++, vector, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos 2d-x and I need to create a Vector of Objects of a Class, but I'm getting a Type Error when I try to create them like this:

```
header
Vector<Vector<Level*> > _stagesLevelsVec;
//Here's the type Error when I try to create a Vector of Vectors of Objects of Class Level
//Error: Invalid Type for cocos2d::Vector<T>!
//Last output line: see reference to class template instantiation 'cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Vector<Level *>>' being compiled
```

cpp

```
Level * level_0 = new Level; //I have to create an Object of Class Level
level_0->setLevel(0); //I have to set a Property of the Object using a Method of the Class.

Vector<Level *> allLevelsVec_0; //Here's the type Error when I try to create a Vector of Objects Level
//Error: Invalid Type for cocos2d::Vector<T>!
//Last output line: see reference to class template instantiation 'cocos2d::Vector<Level *>' being compiled

allLevelsVec_0.pushBack(level_0); //I have to add the Object into the Vector
_stagesLevelsVec.pushBack(allLevelsVec_0); //I have to add a Vector of Objets Level into a Vector

//Then somewhere in code

auto allLevelsVec = _stagesLevelsVec.at(0); // I have to get the Vector of Objects Level that I need
auto level = allLevelsVec.at(0); //I have to get the Object Level
auto levelId = level->getLevel(); //Finally I have to get the Property of level using a Method of the Class

CCLOG("This is level: %i", levelId); //Output must be: This is level: 0.
```

Thanks for any guideline on this matter. Greetings.

Comment: Did you mean `std::vector`? Starting with a small case letter (**v**ector as opposed to **V**ector)?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, I suppose it's `cocos2d::Vector`

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [doc](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Vector%3CT%3E), it seems you try a forbidden declaration :

> **Template parameters**
>
> T - The type of the elements.
>
> T must be the a pointer to a cocos2d::Ref descendant object type. No other data type or primitives are allowed, because we have integrated the memory management model of cocos2d-x into cocos2d::Vector. （since v3.0 beta）

You can't use a `cocos2d::Vector` as type `T`.